# How to put fraction before the parenthesis in SymPy output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I have a SymPy expression that in string format looks like

```
-t*(a+b+c)/2
```

When pretty-printed in LaTeX form (including notebook's LaTeX output), it is too tall and not very easy to read.

How can I combine the fraction and put it before the parenthesis? Like this:

```
(-t/2)*(a+b+c)
```

Code example:

```
from sympy import symbols, Function, Derivative, var, init_printing, pprint, latex

init_printing()
def T(y):
    var('mu')
    return -1 / (2 * mu) * Derivative(y, x, x)

def V(y):
    var('x')
    V = Function('V', commutative=True)(x)
    return V * y

def K(y):
    var('x')
    K = Function('K', commutative=True)(x)
    return K * y

def a1(y):
    var('tau', positive=True)
    return tau * (T(y) + V(y))

def c(A, B):
    def comm(y):
        return A(B(y)) - B(A(y))
    return comm

var('x')
var('t')
f = Function('psi', commutative=False)

c1k = c(a1, K)
print(latex(c1k(f(x,t)).doit().simplify()))
```

Prints and shows

```
- \frac{\tau \left(2 \frac{d}{d x} K{\left (x \right )} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi{\left (x,t \right )} + \frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}} K{\left (x \right )} \psi{\left (x,t \right )}\right)}{2 \mu}
```

I would like to see both in `latex()` and Jupyter notebook

```
-\frac{\tau}{2}\left(...\right)
```

Comment: Can you include some code that shows how to have this expression? (Including import sympy etc.)

Comment: @user4412195 Updated.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and got `- \frac{\tau}{2 \mu} \left( ... ` in SymPy 1.1.1. Maybe update?

Comment: @user4412195 I use today's master branch, which has non-commuting functions fix. Maybe, a regression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SymPy 1.1.1 breaks off pieces of long fractions by default. This led to a [complaint](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14309) which led to a [PR](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/14343) that disabled this behaviour in the current master branch.

To re-enable the previous default, use `long_frac_ratio=2`:

> The allowed ratio of the width of the numerator to the width of the denominator before we start breaking off long fractions. - [SymPy docs](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html#module-sympy.printing.latex)

```
>>> print(latex(c1k(f(x,t)).doit().simplify(), long_frac_ratio=2))
- \frac{\tau}{2 \mu} \left(2 \frac{d}{d x} K{\left (x \right )} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi{\left (x,t \right )} + \frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}} K{\left (x \right )} \psi{\left (x,t \right )}\right)
```

Settings can be included in `init_printing`:

```
init_printing(long_frac_ratio=2)
```

Comment: Is there a simple list of all parameters that can be passed to `init_printing()`? I find the docs a bit confusing.

Comment: @homocomputeris Any parameter that isn't included in the init_printing docstring is passed to the printer, in this case, `latex`. So if you look at the help for `latex` (linked in the answer), it lists the options you can pass.

Comment: As of SymPy 1.3 `'long_frac_ratio' is an invalid keyword argument for print()`